# Naming of non-injective "identity" map

Tags: notation

In an exercise where I want to show that a certain set of vectors $B=\{v_1,v_2,\ldots,v_n\}$ is linearly dependent, I write these vectors with respect to a standard basis $E$ as columns in a matrix. Next, I compute its kernel to show the linear dependence.

This matrix isn't a basis transformation matrix, since the vectors are linearly dependent which makes the matrix non-invertible.

Which nomenclature is appropriate in mentioning this matrix?

With some abuse of notation I could write this matrix as $[id]^B_E: \operatorname{Span}(B) \to \operatorname{Span}(E)$. Namely, the matrix which sends each vector from the ordered set $B$ to its representation in terms of standard basis vector in $E$. But because the matrix is not invertible this notation is misleading, and incorrect.

Or is there no better way of describing this matrix by words then, *the matrix which has the vectors of $B$ as columns with respect to the standard basis*?

Comment: Once the basis $E$ is fixed, you can simply refer to the "column matrix of $B$". Also, you can define a linear function $f : \mathbb{R}^n \to \text{Span}(E)$ by the formula $f(e_i)=v_i$ (where $e_1,...,e_n$ is the standard basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$), and then the matrix of $f$ (with respect to the given standard bases on $\mathbb{R}^n$ and on $\text{Span}(E)$) is equal to the column matrix of $B$.

Comment: @LeeMosher "The column matrix of $B$ with respect to the standard basis $E$", seems like an adequate description, indeed.